# How to fix item.split is not a function

Tags: react-native

I'm setting up a new function and getting an error:
"item.split is not a function"

This is a function for search suggestions so for example 
if I will search the number 7 or 78 so it will return me the error:
"item.split is not a function"

```js
_renderSuggestion = ({ item }) => {
    const splittedName = item.split(' ')
    const splittedSearch = this.state.currentSearch.toUpperCase().split(' ')
    const suggestion = splittedName.map((word, index) =>
      word.toUpperCase().includes(splittedSearch) ? (
        <Text key={index} style={[Style.suggestionText, { color: '#2eb872' }]}>
          {word}{' '}
        </Text>
      ) : (
        <Text key={index} style={Style.suggestionText}>
          {word}{' '}
        </Text>
      )
    )
```

I expect the output will be correct without this error.

Comment: what is the type of item? add the code from where this method is being called

Comment: is the item is of type string??

Comment: `            <FlatList data={this.state.searchAutoComplete} keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()} renderItem={this._renderSuggestion} extraData={this.state} keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always' />
`

Comment: i think its a string

Comment: it will be helpfull if someone will know how to fix this issue

Comment: Inside render() method just console.log and see this.state.searchAutoComplete

Comment: @ Syed 
its show that the "this.state.searchAutoComplete" is an array !
so what shuold i do now ?

Comment: do `console.log(JSON.strigify(this.state.searchAutoComplete))` and put output in question

Comment: its give me big array with data

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
item.toString().split('')
```

The value supplied to the item has to be converted to a string